# ReadStream skipping bytes?

Tags: node.js, linux-kernel, keyboard-events

I'm writing a keyboard-events parser for Linux, using `node.js`. It's working somewhat okay, but sometimes it seems like node is skipping a few bytes. I'm using a [`ReadStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams) to get the data, handle it, process it, and eventually output it when a separator character is encountered (in my case, `\n`).

Here is the part of my class that handles the read data:

```
// This method is called through this callback:
// this.readStream = fs.createReadStream(this.path);
// this.readStream.on("data", function(a) { self.parse_data(self, a); });

EventParser.prototype.parse_data = function(self, data)
{
  /*
   * Data format :
   * {
   *   0x00 : struct timeval time { long sec (8), long usec (8) }        (8  bytes)
   *   0x08 : __u16 type                                                 (2  bytes)
   *   0x10 : __u16 code                                                 (2  bytes)
   *   0x12 : __s32 value                                                (4  bytes)
   * }                                                                 = (16 bytes)
   */

  var dataBuffer = new Buffer(data);
  var slicedBuffer = dataBuffer.slice(0, 16);
  dataBuffer = dataBuffer.slice(16, dataBuffer.length);

  while (dataBuffer.length > 0 && slicedBuffer.length == 16)
  {
    var type = GetDataType(slicedBuffer),
        code = GetDataCode(slicedBuffer),
        value = GetDataValue(slicedBuffer);

    if (type == CST.EV.KEY)
    { // Key was pressed: KEY event type
      if (code == 42 && value == 1) { self.shift_pressed = true; }
      if (code == 42 && value == 0) { self.shift_pressed = false; }

      console.log(type + "\t" + code + "\t" + value + "\t(" + GetKey(self.shift_pressed, code) + ")")
      // GetKey uses a static array to get the actual character
      // based on whether the shift key is held or not

      if (value == 1)
        self.handle_processed_data(GetKey(self.shift_pressed, code));
      // handle_processed_data adds characters together, and outputs the string when encountering a
      // separator character (in this case, '\n')
    }

    // Take a new slice, and loop.
    slicedBuffer = dataBuffer.slice(0, 16);
    dataBuffer = dataBuffer.slice(16, dataBuffer.length);
  }
}

// My system is in little endian!
function GetDataType(dataBuffer)  { return dataBuffer.readUInt16LE(8);  }
function GetDataCode(dataBuffer)  { return dataBuffer.readUInt16LE(10); }
function GetDataValue(dataBuffer) { return dataBuffer.readInt32LE(12);  }
```

I'm basically filling up the data structure explained at the top using a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html). The interesting part is the `console.log` near the end, which will print everything interesting (related to the `KEY` event) that passes in our callback! Here is the result of such log, complete with the expected result, and the actual result:

```
EventParserConstructor: Listening to /dev/input/event19
/* Expected result: CODE-128 */
/* Note that value 42 is the SHIFT key */
1   42  1   ()
1   46  1   (C)
1   42  0   ()
1   46  0   (c)
1   42  1   ()
1   24  1   (O)
1   42  0   ()
1   24  0   (o)
1   42  1   ()
1   32  1   (D)
1   42  0   ()
1   32  0   (d)
1   42  1   ()
1   18  1   (E)
1   42  0   ()
1   18  0   (e)
1   12  0   (-)
1   2   0   (1)
1   3   1   (2)
1   3   0   (2)
1   9   1   (8)
1   9   0   (8)
1   28  1   (
)
[EventParser_Handler]/event_parser.handle_processed_data: CODE28
/* Actual result: CODE28 */
/* The '-' and '1' events can be seen in the logs, but only */
/* as key RELEASED (value: 0), not key PRESSED */
```

We can clearly see the `-` and `1` character events passing by, but only as key releases (value: 0), not key presses. The weirdest thing is that most of the time, the events are correctly translated. But 10% of the time, this happens.

Is `ReadStream` eating up some bytes, occasionally? If yes, what alternative should I be using?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, turns out that my loop was rotten.

I was assuming that the data would only come in chunks of 16 bytes... Which obviously isn't always the case. So sometimes, I had packets of <16 bytes being left over and lost between two `'data'` event callbacks.

I added this by adding an `excessBuffer` field to my class and using it to fill my initial `slicedBuffer` when receiving data.